# Is it possible to do a computation dynamically in an html form without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was told it's possible to compute something in an HTML form without reloading it and without using Javascript - something like having three input fields (`a`, `b` and `c`) where `c` shows the computation of `a+b`. He told me this could be done using the HTML5 tag `output`. After some googling I only found examples that use `oninput` and then some computation function that's called within the output element. Can this be called JavaScript free? If so, is there any reference to convince me? If not, is there any reference to convince my workmate? Or is there any other option do achieve a live computation inside an HTML form with only using HTML or maybe PHP?

Comment: No it will not be JavaScript free

Comment: HTML is not a programming language

Comment: Why don't you ask your workmate to show you how it's done?

Comment: "is it possible?" [technically yes](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/calculator2.html#nogo), but don't waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

**Not even HTML5 alone will accomplish data computations.** PHP can do this, but the form must be submitted, passing the data to a PHP script via variables and reloading the page. This is probably not the "live" computation you are looking for. Use Javascript for this case if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you maybe have any reference (an article on a somehow serious website or something like that) for me saying exactly what you wrote?